# Connecting database in another server

Tags: php, sql, database, rhel

For a web project we have been provided two servers, one for web and another for database. When i try to connecting to the database in another server i get "Cannot connect permission denied" error. I wanted to know if i have to change any settings or modify any files like php.ini or cnf etc for it to work? I am running php 7.2 on rhel 7.5 servers. Also i changed root to allow all hosts(%) in users.

```
$db_host        = '172.xx.xx.xx';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = 'passwrd';
$db_database    = 'some_db';

/* End config */


$db_conx = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the "root" user has admin privileges or try creating a new user and grant it full admin right privileges.

```
% mysql --user=root mysql
CREATE USER 'youruser'@'yourserver' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'youruser'@'yourserver' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: it says ALL PRIVILEGES in global privileges column in the user table

Comment: you also have to set the database to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.  In my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

By default you cannot access mysql from remote ip address. First of all, you need to grant all access to root,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you need to unbind the ip address part in mysql ini file, which should look like `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` , either delete it or comment it by `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.
After changing all these, restart mysql service to take effect of changes.
Note: THe above location is for windows environment, if you are in linux, then likely location may be `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, some cases it may be in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.